# Y/N Loop Not exiting

Tags: c, loops

```
int main()
{
    int     valid_input;    /* when 1, data is valid and loop is exited */
    char    user_input;     /* handles user input, single character menu choice */

    valid_input = 0;
    while (valid_input == 0)
    {
        printf("Continue (Y/N)?\n");
        scanf_s("  %c", &user_input);
        user_input = toupper(user_input);

        if ((user_input == 'Y') || (user_input == 'N'))
            valid_input = 1;
        else
            printf("\007Error: Invalid choice\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No matter what character is entered the loop will not exit. I may be blind as I can't see what's wrong with the code. someone with better vision please help!

Comment: Try to cast the return of toupper() as char

Comment: Can you use a debugger? What is the value of `user_input` after entering `Y`?

Comment: What happens if you press `Enter`?

Comment: don't use `scanf()` for getting user input – it's inherently flawed. Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the space before %c in scanf_s.

```
Example:
scanf_s("%c", &var);
```

It worked on my machine.

Comment: In this explanation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ it becomes not so clear what the supposed behavious is if more than one space chacter precedes a non-space format character.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant!

Comment: extremely weird, maybe my Visual Studio is not installed correctly, as I just tried that and its not working for me still. With no space I get 
Error: Invalid choice
Continue (Y/N)?
Error: Invalid choice
Continue (Y/N)? printed out.

Comment: Ok, then use `var = getch();`

Comment: sick that works, no enter key required too, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, to read a character you need:

```
scanf_s("  %c", &user_input, 1);
```

[scanf_s documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)